# How to force specific ciphersuites in the client-side when connecting to SQL Server?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, security, tls1.2

I have enabled TLS1.2 on Microsoft SQL Server and the client is connecting to it using Entity Framework and the TLS connection is established successfully.

The problem is that I'm trying to get a security certificate for my application and the evaluators told that I need to force specific ciphersuites at the client-side.

I've googled for days and didn't find any way to implement a C# application which force a specific client-side ciphersuite for establishing TLS connection to SQL Server.

Is there any way to do it? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Unlike HTTP, as far as I know, it's not possible to do this on a per-application basis for TDS. Both client and server code completely rely on SChannel (the native Windows implementation of SSL) for protocol negotiation, with no exposed knobs for tuning. The best you can do is configure this [globally](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows-server/security/tls/tls-registry-settings) to exclude insecure protocols and prioritize more secure ones, but it is not technically possible to force specific suites.